# Different hotkeys for pinned tabs

Tags: chromium, tabs

Chromium has a `Pin Tab` feature that keeps certain pages open constantly. It also has a keyboard shortcut, `control + 1-8`, which can select a specific tab from the tab list. Could I set different shortcuts for pinned and unpinned tabs (for example, Control for pinned tabs and Alt for unpinned tabs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't do this without an extension. One thing you may consider (and I share this because it's my latest obsession) is making your most used pinned tabs into desktop apps, using nativefier (I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hFaoNuyidM) to learn how to do that), and then you can just switch to the relevant app using those shortcuts (granted, this requires a couple more keystrokes in some cases). But, that's not what you asked for. I haven't given it a test drive for this purpose, but its possible that the [Shortkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck) extension would let you do this, or may add support for that feature in the future.

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit my question if shortkeys has what I need